# Next js On-Demand Revalidation on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

It may be simply that firebase hosting at this moment does not support Next js On-Demand Revalidation for ISR.

Issue: No matter how many times i trigger the api route to revalidate `res.revalidate(path)` , the page just does to update.

Is there something unique that is required for next js on-demand revalidation for firebase hosting

Answer (score 0):

this is not supported as of 19th Jan 2024

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5680